# Scrape Renewal Pricing From Go Daddy' pricing list

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping

https://www.godaddy.com/domains/popups/chart.aspx

I am wanting to scrape the renew pricing for the general TLDs for the popular domains.

I am looking for the source code but not seeing the price numbers.... Where are these variables found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prices are generated dynamically after the page's load... here's the link of prices of the default table

https://www.godaddy.com/domains/controls/jsoncontent/generalpricing.aspx?tab=general&widthreduction=160&hidelinks=true&TargetDivId=tabgj_new&regt=new&_=1380620289373

It returns a json file that could be parsed using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

To see what's dynamically changing while interacting with the page, In chrome, launch the `developper tools` then `Network` tab from the top and `XHR` tab from the bottom...

In that tab you'll see all dynamic communications between the website and the server

### Edit:

Here's a working example:

```
// includes Simple HTML DOM Parser
require_once "php/lib/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php";

$url = "https://www.godaddy.com/domains/controls/jsoncontent/generalpricing.aspx?tab=general&widthreduction=160&hidelinks=true&TargetDivId=tabgj_new&regt=new&_=1380620289373";

// Download json file and converts it into a PHP variable
$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

// get html data from the json object
$htmlData = $jsonData->Html;


/*
 * Parse the HTML DOM using Simple HTML DOM Parser
 */

//Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($htmlData);

// Print results
foreach($html->find("table tr") as $index => $row) {

    switch ($index) {

        case '0':   // Print table header
            foreach($row->find("th") as $col) {
                echo $col->plaintext;
                echo " | ";
            }
            echo "<br/>---<br/>";
            break;

        default:    // Print all rows
            foreach($row->find("td") as $col) {
                echo $col->plaintext;
                echo " | ";
            }
            echo "<br/>---<br/>";
            break;
    }
}


OUTPUT:
-------
Per year pricing | 1 year | 2 years | 3 years | 5 years | 10 years | 
---
.COM | $12.99* $14.99* | $13.99* $14.99* | $14.33* $14.99* | $14.59* $14.99* | $14.79* $14.99* | 
---
.CO | $12.99 $29.99 | $21.49 $29.99 | $24.33 $29.99 | $26.59 $29.99 | -- | 
---
.INFO | $2.99* $14.99* | $8.99* $14.99* | $10.99* $14.99* | $12.59* $14.99* | $13.79* $14.99* | 
---
.ORG | $9.99* $17.99* | $13.99* $17.99* | $15.33* $17.99* | $16.39* $17.99* | $17.19* $17.99* | 
---
.NET | $9.99* $16.99* | $13.49* $16.99* | $14.66* $16.99* | $15.59* $16.99* | $16.29* $16.99* | 
---
.ME | $9.99 $19.99 | $14.99 $19.99 | $16.66 $19.99 | $17.99 $19.99 | $18.99 $19.99 | 
---
.MOBI | $9.99* $17.99* | $13.99* $17.99* | $15.33* $17.99* | $16.39* $17.99* | $17.19* $17.99* | 
---
.US | $3.99 $19.99 | $11.99 $19.99 | $14.66 $19.99 | $16.79 $19.99 | $18.39 $19.99 | 
---
.BIZ | $6.99* $16.99* | $11.99* $16.99* | $13.66* $16.99* | $14.99* $16.99* | $15.99* $16.99* | 
---
.CA | $12.99 | $12.99 | $12.99 | $12.99 | $12.99 | 
---
.CC | $19.99 | $19.99 | $19.99 | $19.99 | $19.99 | 
---
.LA | $39.99 | $39.99 | $39.99 | $39.99 | $39.99 | 
---
.TV | $39.99 | $39.99 | $39.99 | $39.99 | $39.99 | 
---
.WS | $15.99 | $15.99 | $15.99 | $15.99 | $15.99 | 
---
.ASIA | $19.99* | $19.99* | $19.99* | $19.99* | $19.99* | 
---
.XXX | $99.99* | $99.99* | $99.99* | $99.99* | $99.99* | 
---
```

Comment: How would I parse the JSON? Would I pull the html part and then run a HTML parser to get the renewal prices from the table?

Comment: Ow, I didnt notice it contains html code... But that's the idea, you get the html code then you parse it using some dom parser such as [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)... I'll post an example later...

Comment: @user1512405, example added... You can refer to [Simple HTML DOM Parser's documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) for more details